# How to give access to registry.bin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I open my Android Studio 3.0.1, the Gradle build fails. The error is shown below.

[image]

It was working fine before, and I don't remember to have made any changes to its settings. However, now it won't go any further.

Please help, I'm stuck!

Comment: try to run Android studio as **Run as administrator** and check.

Comment: @Jaymin I tried. But it's still the same. I even uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio. Still stuck on the same problem.

Comment: delete cache folder insider /.gradle folder.

Comment: @Jaymin deleted .gradle folder, and rebuilt the project, and it got fixed.  thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Close Android Studio and try deleting the C:\Users\Mansoor.gradle directory and rebuild your project.
2. If 1st solution not works then go to C:\Users\Mansoor.gradle\daemon\gradle version and delete registry.bin.lock file. Rebuild Project then.

Comment: Deleting the .gradle directory solved it for me. Thanks for that, spent 3 days figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the access denied file was located in a hidden folder (caches), once unchecked ‘hidden’, it was working

Comment: It'll be great if you can add a screenshot to show how to uncheck 'hidden'

Comment: @PatrickKen to uncheck 'hidden', find the file in explorer -> right click it -> properties -> in 'general' tab look in the last section, you have 2 checkboxes, one of them is 'hidden' -> uncheck it.