# Gradle sync failed: registry.bin (Access is denied)

Tags: gradle, synchronization

I am a beginner in Android Studio, I am getting below error message.

Gradle sync failed: .gradle\daemon\5.6.4\registry.bin (Access is denied)

Pls help me out from this issue.

Ashish Bhatia

Comment: the message says `Access is denied` - go and get the required access

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give access to registry.bin in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698299/how-to-give-access-to-registry-bin-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps:-

Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Shutdown Android Studio

Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory

Restart Android Studio (It will download gradle metadata and data)

Gradle build succeed

Rebuild project. Done.

This worked for me.